# App does not appear in Per-app language settings

Tags: android, android-13

I'm currently trying to support per-app languages for my app.
I followed [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages):

- I created `locales_config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale_config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <locale android:name="en-US"/>
    <locale android:name="fr"/>
</locale_config>
```

which I added in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"
```

- In `app/build.gradle`, I added:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en_US", "fr"
    }
}
```

---

My problem is that **my app does not appear in Per-app language settings**.
I tested it on both an emulator and a phone running stable Android 13.

Additional info:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2
compileSdkVersion 33
```

If anyone got this working, I'd like to know if there's any other additional step I'm missing.

**Edit:**
It doesn't work either when replacing both `en-US` and `en_US` with `en`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root element in `locales_config.xml` must be `<locale-config>`, but in your xml I see `<locale_config>` (underscore should be a hypen).

Update your `locales_config.xml` to the text below, and it will work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <locale android:name="en-US"/>
    <locale android:name="fr"/>
</locale-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default locale is always: `<locale android:name="en"/>` and not `en-US` or `en-GB`.

Comment: It may be part of the problem, but I still don't see my app in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue and it turns out my issue was that I didn't put the `android:localeConfig="@xml/locale_config"` in the right place in the manifest.

It's supposed to be associated with the `application` tag:

```
<application android:localeConfig="@xml/locale_config" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" ...
```

(Also, check that the name you specify there matches your XML filename. `@xml/locale_config` implies a "locale_config.xml" file saved in the `xml` resource folder.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my app was already set up like that. I tried renaming `locales_config.xml` to `locale_config.xml`, without any result.

Comment: @Tim241 Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml and locales_config.xml files in full, as well as where they appear in your directory structure? The problem might be as simple as a typo.